# How to improve speed of loading maps in leaflet with very heavy geojson?

Tags: leaflet, qgis

I'm working with a web map generated from QGis but the data files are very heavy, the map takes a long time to load and the navigation is impossible. How can solve this problem?

Comment: Don't use geojson, fetch png tiles which are small and fast to load

Comment: Hi Ian! can you get me any example url? thanks!

Comment: search for WMS and leaflet